# Rigify pose Issue Mesh Deforming on knee

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

I have this problem with my leg rigging.

Every time I move it up with IK Leg it would bend the opposite direction which would make my character look like a Centaur. Cool but not what I'm aiming for.

Why does it do that but I think it could be because of how I created my character. I created him facing the back view. So when I added my Human meta rig, I rotated it 180 so it can face backwards. 
If that's the reason why can someone please tell me how I can fix that with out starting a new Human Meta Rig?

Here's what happened when I tried to fix it by placing the knee's target in the front instead of the back.
[image]

Here's how it looks when I don't fix it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the support Candice babe. But I finally figured it out! Woo Hoo!

Alright so I figured out that my Z Axis in the legs were facing the wrong direction of the Original Human Meta Rig Armature.

So then I was like, That looks wrong. I fixed it but I still had an Issue.

But Then I finally figured out I had to fix the Z Axis of my Foot's Roll. Makes perfect Sense.

So all in all for those of you with this issue.
Look for your armature's Foot IK (Which should be that little bone sticking out from the back of your foot) Find that, click it and press N to open your Window.
Next! Scroll to the top in that window and find Roll.
Change the Z Roll till it's pointing Downwards/Backwards and Bam! You got it fixed.

Tip: Now if you want to make a Horseman Just make your Roll face towards the front or   The Opposite Direction.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you recalculate your avatar's point of origin it should reset the ik bone.

Go into Edit mode.
Select the Shading/UV tab.
Choose Recalculate.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for giving an answer. But I'm kind of confused.
When I press N to open the window and scroll down to the shading tab it only gives me these options.

GLSL,
Textured Solid,
Matcap,
Back face Culling,
and 
Hiddden Wire.

btw can you please tell me what you ment by avatar? Did you mean my Armature, my Character Mesh or my Rig? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, I mean your character mesh AND skeleton when I say Avatar. When you are in Edit mode, because each version of Blender varies a bit, press the spacebar and type in Recalculate. That may be the easiest way to find it. I'm relatively new to Blender myself. My boss has been using it for years and taught me how to fix the same issue you're having by recalculating the model. =)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too and neither of your solutions helped at all. I tested the default rig to see what was different from mine and I realized that the model I was rigging had their knees bent more backwards and that I was setting the bones to fit.

Solution was to move the kneecap so the hip and ankle are at a forward bend (or place the bone endpoints to be out of/at the knee, not in the leg). I could probably do this with the generated rig, but it adds midpoint bones and etc, and it was just easier to just regenerate from the metarig (which overwrites the previous rig, if it's un-renamed, while retaining pose and such changes).